# How do i split up user input into both string and integer values in the same function and return them both separately. c++

Tags: c++

i am new to c++ and was trying out a little task. I am stuck on figuring out how to split up an integer and character which has come from the users input and return both values back to the caller. I know functions can only return a single value so i tried using structs to create two variables and then asked the user for their input and split it up but it couldn't get anywhere with it. Is there an easier solution to this, bearing in mind i am purposefully creating separate functions for all separate pieces?

The goal is to take the users' input from a single line, split up the text so we know both the integer value and the temp, return these values, and then use another function to convert and another to print, and so on..

Here is the code:

```
#include "TempHead.h"

#include  <iostream>


int main(){

    int x {readCharInput()};
    int y{readTempInput()};
    int g{Converter(x,y)};

    Print(g);

    return 0;
}



void Print(int x){
    std::cout << "Your converted temperture is: " << x;
}


#if 0

struct foo(){

    int x{};
    char y{};
    

}


foo temp(){


}

 #endif

int readTempInput(){

    std::string x{};
    std::string y{};

    std::cout << "Please enter the tempertaure you would like to convert in format (int/char): ";

    std::getline(std::cin, x, '/');
    std::getline(std::cin, y, '/');
 

    return x, y;

}


int Converter(char x, int y){

    int Conv{};

    if(x == 'C'){
        Conv = (y - 32) * 0.5556;

    }else if (x == 'F')
    {
        Conv = y * 1.8 + 32;
    }
    
    return Conv;
}
```

this is what i was attempting to do with struts,i dont fully understand so i gave it a shot but couldn't get it to work.

```
struct readTemp{

    int value{};
    char y{};
    

};


readTemp tempRead(){


     std::string x{};
     std::string y{};

    std::cout << "Please enter the tempertaure you would like to convert in format (int/char): ";

    std::getline(std::cin, x, '/');
   //std::getline(std::cin, y, '/');
    std::cin >> y;
 

    readTemp read = {x,y};
    
    return read;

}
```

Comment: Lets see what you tried with the `struct`. It's a good solution to your problem. The code you have shown cannot be made to work, so better to focus on a solution that can work.

Comment: Please post the code that you described: with `struct` containing integer and string, and function returning it. Because what you wrote sounds reasonable: just read the line, split it into 2 strings, convert one of them to integer, leave the other one as it is, return the struct containing both.

Comment: Side note: organize the code better. You want to provide a code example that people can paste into their tools and immediately see the problem you are facing. If they have to move stuff around or add stuff they may insert new problems and give an answer to those problems or accidentally fix the problem and give no answer at all.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all your comments. I appreciate the quick reply, i have added my attempt at using struts.

Answer (score 0):

`readTemp read = {x,y};` requires `x` r be an `int` and `y` to be a `char`. They are both `std::string`s.

A possible solution:

```cpp
readTemp tempRead(){


     std::string x{};
     std::string y{};

     std::cout << "Please enter the temperature you would like to convert in format (int/char): ";

     std::getline(std::cin, x, '/');
     std::getline(std::cin, y); // assuming user input will be ended by the user hitting enter.
 

    readTemp read = {
        std::stoi(x), // convert to int. Exception on failure
        y.size()==1? // if y is exactly 1 character
            y[0]: // provide that one character
            throw std::runtime_error("didn't get a character")}; // exception on failure
    
    return read;
}
```

Note that [`std::stoi(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) might not be good enough. It doesn't parse the whole sting, just up to the end of a valid `int`. There could be garbage on the end that is ignored. Rather than ignoring the garbage you may want to reject the input.

Comment: Hi, when i try and convert the string to int using std::stovi it throws an 'error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'std::string''.

Comment: That sounds like `x` is already an `int` or `readTemp::value` is a `std::string`, not an `int`. Not enough information to tell you which or if you have a later problem with completely different code.